# PHP. Вопрос по регулярному выражение, вставка класса в тег

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть некий навигационный блок:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li>
        <a class="text-mutten" href="/link1">Пункт 1</a>
    </li>
    <li class='test other-cls'>
        <a href="/link2">Пункт 2</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="/link3">Пункт 3</a>
    </li>
    <li class="">
        <a class="text-mutten active" href="/link4">Пункт 4</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

И дан определяющий параметр вставки по *href*.
например, **param = 'link2'**

Регулярное выражение должно просмотреть, в каких *href* есть вхождение 'link2'
И там где нашлось, добавить в "LI" родителя класс "active"

т.е. в нашем примере li *class=*'test other-cls' превратится в *class=*'test other-cls active'

Как бы изящно это реализовать?

Answer (score 0):

Решил задачу сам. Вряд ли кому пригодится, и не уверен, что решение нормальное, но все же:

$block - это наш навигационный блок;
$param - что ищем.

```
$block = preg_replace_callback("/\<li(.*?)class=(.*?)(active)(.*?)\>/sui", function ($match) {
        $cl = trim($match[2]) . trim($match[4]);
        return '<li' . $match[1] . (!empty($cl) ? 'class=' . $cl : '') . '>';
    }, $block);


    if (preg_match_all("/\<li(.*?)href=[\"|'](.*?)[\"|'](.*?)li\>/sui", $block, $matchs)) {
        $i = -1;
        foreach ($matchs[2] as $key => $match) {
            if (strpos($match, $param) !== false) {
                $i = $key;
                break;
            }
        }
        if ($i >= 0) {
            if (strpos($matchs[0][$i], 'class') !== false) {
                $matchs[0][$i] = preg_replace("/class=([\"|'])/sui", 'class=$1active ', $matchs[0][$i]);
            } else {
                $matchs[0][$i] = preg_replace("/\<li/sui", '<li class="active"', $matchs[0][$i]);
            }
        }
        $block = implode($matchs[0], '');
    }
```

Comment: Если у вас это одна статичная страничка то все норм. А если это страница со стороннего сервиса то лучше этот код переделать с использованием domdocument. Потому что регулярки очень плохо сочетаются с html/xml кодом.